# Open a popup box after receiving result from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, popup

i have a ajax code that works properly and gives the desired result. I want to modify this code and want that when a reply is received from ajax a popup/modal box should get opened.

I am able to open popup/modal box on a click of a button

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bsModal3">
    Small Modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="bsModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="mySmallModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Your content goes here...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but don't know how to open it automatically within ajax.

here is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'test2.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        txt: txtbox,
        hidden: hiddenTxt
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (returndata) {
        if (returndata[4] === 1) {
            // want to load a popup box here
        } else {
            // other code
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
    }
});
```

can anyone please tell me how it can be done

Comment: Just copy your code you used to open the modal by click, no ?

Comment: What kind of "modal" window you want to open. Can you provide the code you use on click?

Comment: _"am able to open popup/modal box on a click of a button"_ `success: function (returndata) { $("button").click()}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$("#bsModal3").modal('show');` inside your result.

See more about modal [methods](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods)

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'test2.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    txt: txtbox,
    hidden: hiddenTxt
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function(returndata) {
    if (returndata[4] === 1) {

      $("#bsModal3").modal('show');

    } else {
      // other code
    }
  },
  error: function() {
    console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="bsModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="mySmallModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Your content goes here...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try put this inside success callback :

```
success: function (returndata) {
    if (returndata[4] === 1) {
        $('#bsModal3').modal(); // this
    } else {
        // other code
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do with the Ajax Call,modal is call in ajax response

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'test2.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            txt: txtbox,
            hidden: hiddenTxt
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (returndata) {
            if (returndata[4] === 1) {
               $('#bsModal3').modal();  // Please right this in your Code
            } else {
                // other code
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'test2.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    txt: txtbox,
    hidden: hiddenTxt
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function(returndata) {
    if (returndata[4] === 1) {

      $("#bsModal3").modal('show');

    } else {
      // other code
    }
  },
  error: function() {
    console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="bsModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="mySmallModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Your content goes here...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```