# Passing data to popup Modal without Bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, html, popup

I am trying to pass data to a popup modal without bootstrap.
I just need to pass over a id so that i can get data from server using the id to display data in form. This is for the user to edit data.

I am using onclick as a method to open popup modal. 
If possible i want to keep on using onclick. So is there any method to pass data to popup modal using onclick? Is it possible to us php as a method for onclick?

HTML:

```
<button id="myBtn" class="" `onclick="document.getElementById'('Modaluprec').style.display='block'">Done</button>`

<div id="Modaladdrec" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('Modaladdrec').style.display='none'" class="close">&times;</span>
                <form autocomplete="off" class="patform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost/FYP/php/addrec.php>" method="POST">
                    <div class="container">
                        <label style="text-align:center" class="header2"><h2>Update Patient</h2></label>
                        <label>Height</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Height" name="height" value="">
                        <label>Weight</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Weight" name="weight" value="">
                        <button class="buttonsubmit" type="submit" name="submit">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I did not give all the code. I only add in important codes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this one will help you.

[Open a popup box after receiving result from ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029730/open-a-popup-box-after-receiving-result-from-ajax)

you can load your data from DB and pass it by ajax through your javascript modal.

Comment: I think that guys is using bootstrap